# Shortcut to jump between declaration and implementation in XE7

Tags: c++builder, shortcut

I have been at this for hours. I want to rip my eyes out. 
We use XE7 C++Builder. Is there a simple shortcut that allows a poor programmer like me to easily jump between the declaration of a method in a header file, to the implementation in the cpp file, and vice versa?

I found this [link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Default_Keyboard_Shortcuts) which says `Shift+Ctrl+Down Arrow` and `Shift+Ctrl+Up Arrow` should do it, but they don't. They simply don't work.

I know I can hover with the mouse and hold `Ctrl` on the keyboard, but this only opens the declaration. I want a simple shortcut to move in either direction (implementation to declaration and vice-versa).

Is there something else that needs to be enabled (in Tools>Options>Editor Options>Key Mappings )?

Comment: I hit F12 (open cpp) then Ctrl-F and function name... would be nice to have the feature you are looking for!

Comment: Like Matt, but first I hit Ctrl-F in the header file with the cursor at the beginning of the function name, which auto-populates the search box with the function name, then press Enter. Then I hit Ctrl-F6 (switch to cpp file), and then F3 (next instance of search).

Comment: Thank you both. @Anthony I like this approach, if you post it as an answer I will accept. Still can't believe there isn't just one shortcut for this, but I'll work with your approach for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in the header file with the cursor at the beginning of the function name, which auto-populates the search box with the function name, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> (switch to cpp file), and then <kbd>F3</kbd> (next instance of search).